# Issues in manipulation script of arcore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

I tried the object manipulation scene and is unable to move the instantiated object across the scene as well as elevate the object.

And another issue I felt was when I tap on a location that already has an object another new object is being instantiated. Should this be possible?

Also is there a size limit on how much we can increase the size of an object, and if so how do we change that?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TakeScreenshot : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    GameObject blink;
    public Text text;

    public void TakeAShot()
    {
        StartCoroutine ("CaptureIt");
    }

    IEnumerator CaptureIt()
    {
        string timeStamp = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss");
        string fileName = "Screenshot" + timeStamp + ".png";
        string pathToSave = fileName;
        text.text = fileName;
        ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(pathToSave);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        print("screenshot taken");
        print(fileName);
        Instantiate (blink, new Vector2(0f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are asking multiple unrelated questions here. Please [split them up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts). Your first question, about manipulating objects will also need some details. What [have you tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I have only imported the default sample scene

Comment: I have split the questions @artcorpse

Comment: I can't find the two split questions. Could you please maybe link them here?